# How to iterate through entire Windows registry and delete any keys with the name/value of a string/char/data?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

Basically, I want to iterate through the entire Windows registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, HKEY_USERS, HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG` and delete every key that has a title or data that contains a string/char/any type of data. Issue is, I have no idea how I would actually approach this.

I've already seen snippets of code looking for keys with a name such as:

```
subkey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,subkey,0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    dwType = REG_SZ;
    if( RegQueryValueEx(hKey,"AVG_TRAY",0,&dwType,(BYTE*)buffer,&dwBufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        cout << "key value is'" << buffer << "'\n";
    }
    else
        cout << "can not query for key value\n";
}
```

or something like

```
int GetPaths()
{
    char buffer[255] = {0};
    DWORD dwBufferSize = sizeof(buffer);
    const char* subkey;
    string values[100]; // Max 100 values.
    string Paths[100]; // Max 100 paths.
    DWORD dwType = 0;
    HKEY hKey = 0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    subkey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
    if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,subkey,0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        dwType = REG_SZ;
        /** Here a loop that would call a function 
         * that would retrieve the name of the first
         * value into values[i] (i would be 0 initially)
         * and then increment 1 to i and loop again.
         * The value would be the next one and its
         * name would be save in values[i] (i would be
         * 1 this time). It would keep until all the
         * values in hKey would have been read.
         */
         while( i =< hKey.numberofvalues )
         {
             GetValueName(from HKey, valuenumber i, into buffer);
             values[i] = buffer;
             i++;
         }
         /** Now a loop to get the data of thoose values
          * (values[j]) into buffer and then into Paths[j].
          */
         while( j =< i )
         {
             if(RegQueryValueEx(hKey,values[j],0,&dwType,(BYTE*)buffer,&dwBufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
             {
                 Paths[j] = buffer;
                 j++;
             }
             else
                cout << "Could not query value from " << hKey << endl;
         }
    }
    else
        cout << "Could not open key " << subkey << endl;

    cout << "Got paths from registry successfully." << endl;
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

but they don't answer my question.
If anyone could help me out, it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for [`RegEnumKeyEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regenumkeyexw) and [`RegQueryInfoKeyEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryinfokeyw). See [Enumerating Registry Subkeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/enumerating-registry-subkeys).

Comment: Hi zjf, have you check the "Enumerating Registry Subkeys" as @RemyLebeau pointed out? It helps you solve the issue?